# Converting Longitude range from (0,360) to (-180,180) in Python or by using gdal commands

Tags: qgis, python, raster, gdal, rotate

I have a raster downloaded.
Visualising it in QGIS.
[image]

I want to correctly project it so that its extent varies with longitudes from -180 to 180 instead of 0 to 360.

`gdalinfo filename.nc` outputs the following as the corner coordinates

```
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  -0.1250000,  90.1250000) 
Lower Left  (  -0.1250000, -90.1250000) 
Upper Right (     359.875,      90.125) 
Lower Right (     359.875,     -90.125) 
Center      ( 179.8750000,   0.0000000)
```

I am looking for a `gdal` command or python function to perform this task of rotating the image such that longitudes vary from -180 to 180.

Similar questions:

1. [Verifying formula that will convert longitude 0-360 to -180 to 180?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201789/verifying-formula-that-will-convert-longitude-0-360-to-180-to-180) (Fortran solution)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730625/how-to-convert-longitude-from-0-360-to-180-180 (R function of rotation)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of reprojecting the whole data you may try to set the correct projection for your raster. Similar questions:

[How to reproject raster from 0 360 to -180 180 with cutting 180 meridian](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37790/how-to-reproject-raster-from-0-360-to-180-180-with-cutting-180-meridian)

[WKT for EPSG:4326 with LON 0 to +360 instead of -180 to +180](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256215/wkt-for-epsg4326-with-lon-0-to-360-instead-of-180-to-180)